Quantum Mechanical Transformation of the Position Three-Vector
My question is reg sec 12.2 of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics where the author describes the transformation of 2D position and momentum under rotation. He talks about position and momentum states $ |x,y\rangle,|p_x,p_y\rangle$ transforming, under rotation by $\phi$ to $ |x\cos\phi-y\sin \phi,x\sin \phi+y\cos\phi\rangle,|p_x\cos\phi-p_y\sin \phi,p_x\sin \phi+p_y\cos\phi\rangle$. The same is stated for expectations of $X,Y$, which I write here only for $X$:$$\langle X\rangle_R=\langle X\rangle\cos \phi-\langle Y\rangle\sin\phi...(1)$$
The text says that $\langle X\rangle_R$ could carry an additional phase factor $g(x,y)$ which can be omitted in order to make $\langle P_x\rangle, \langle P_y\rangle$ transform in the same way. I do not understand how. 
Consider $ X \to X\cos\phi-Y\sin \phi $. Since $|\psi_R\rangle,|\psi\rangle$ only differ by a phase, $$\implies \langle\psi_R|X|\psi_R\rangle=\langle\psi|X|\psi\rangle \cos\phi-
\langle\psi|Y|\psi\rangle \sin\phi$$ which yields Eq (1). Please help me understand how $g(x,y)$ comes into the picture.

Could $g(x,y)$ be a global phase, i.e. $x \to g(x,y) (x \cos \phi - y \sin \phi) $ where $g$ has unit norm $|g(x,y)| = 1$? Such a global phase can always be introduced in quantum mechanical expressions since the physics only depend on the norm square of the wave function, meaning the phase vanishes.
